# how to add multiple parameter in java constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

How can I add barCodeNum and price in the parameter?
I tried to add those with comma but it shows some error.
Hope you could help me out.

```
package shop;

public class BuyItem {
    private String buyDate;
    private int quantity;
    private String barCodeNum;
    public int price;
    public BuyItem(String buyItem, int quantity) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What, where and when you got error. Look like you need to read more on java and tried same.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) and especially the part about how to ask proper questions and then edit your question. As it is it's very likely being closed quite fast.

Comment: Please add the code in your question, not a link to a .png file. You can format the code with the {} button.

Comment: this is not how so works. Please provide your code, objectives and error. You probably need some basic tutorial on Java.

Comment: Please add the exact error message you are getting. I suspect you need to add another constructor, not change the existing one because it might be already used. So you will receive compilation errors. But that's only a shot into the blue - please add stacktrace or compilation error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. 
Please look up the concepts of object oriented programming https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

You want to define new parameters as type + parametername like Pirate wrote in his answer. Different parameters are separated by commas. 
Try

```
package shop;

public class MyShop{
    private String buyDate;
    private int quantity;
    private String barCodeNum;
    public int price;
        public MyShop(String buyItem, int quantity, String barCodeNum, int price) {
this.barCodeNum = barCodeNum;
this.price = price;
        }
    }
```

And:
Classes represent objects like "Shop" and own methods like "buyItem()".
NOTE, that I renamed your class and therefore the constructor, too

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
class A{
    A(String a,String b){
       System.out.print(a);
       System.out.print(b);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        A obj=new A("Stack","OverFlow");
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: You _might_ consider adding some explanation, otherwise it's actually not more than what the OP already has and just throwing some code at him won't teach him anything.

Comment: And you are outputting String a twice instead of a and b. So that code is even buggy ;)

Comment: [okay i am trying it. does it prints the information in main method?

Comment: It will create a object of class A and when the object is created the constructor is called and print the passing string. Output will be StackOverFlow.